# CXF: Implement multiple ports on same soap:adress?

Tags: soap, wsdl, jax-ws, cxf, wsdl2java

We got a WSDL from a client, asking us to implement the service on our side.

The WSDL contains 3 port-bindings, with different names and bindings, but identical `<soap:adress>` --- like this:

```
<port name="Name1" binding="tns:Binding1">
    <soap:address location="http://localhost/Service/ServicePort" />
</port>
<port name="Name2" binding="tns:Binding2">
    <soap:address location="http://localhost/Service/ServicePort" />
</port>
<port name="Name3" binding="tns:Binding3">
    <soap:address location="http://localhost/Service/ServicePort" />
</port>
```

**Is such WSDL possible to implement with CXF?**

When I run **wsdl2java**, CXF generates 3 java-interfaces.

I first tried a single implementation-class, like

```
class MyServiceClass implements Interface1, Interface2, Interface3 {...}
```

But when I deployed it and checked with SoapUI, for some reason, 
it would only expose Port-binding for `Interface1`, 
and seemed to ignore the 2 other ones. **Why?**

I then tried instead, to implement 3 different ServiceClasses (each implementing one of the interfaces),
then put multiple `<jaxws:endpoint>` with identical `address` attributes in **cxf-config.xml**

But I then get deployment-error:

```
RuntimeException: Soap 1.1 endpoint already registered on address /Address
```

Any hints, how to implement such WSDL in CXF? 
Is it possible?

Comment: http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/implementor-multiple-WebService-implemented-interfaces-td568283.html seems related (but not helpful).

Answer (score 3):

```
      But when I deployed it and checked with SoapUI, for some reason, it would only expose Port-binding for Interface1, and seemed to ignore the 2 other ones. Why?
```

If you will see your implementation class, you will find this annotation,

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "yourPackageName.Interface1")
```

Which is referring to your interface1 only. That's why on deploying it is ignoring rest 2 interface implementations.

So, you have to implement these 3 interface separately in different implemenataion class as you did as per your explanantion. Because only one endpointInterface is allowed in each implementation class.

```
Is such WSDL possible to implement with CXF?
```

Yes, it is possible.

During the deployement in your endpoint publisher class, you need to wrap these 3 interface implementation class object in one object and publish for a single end point.

I am still not clear how to do that, ill update the answer later.

Few useful links: It's same requirement but little confusing.

http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/Deploying-multiple-endpoints-ports-for-a-service-td569470.html

Also read about JavaBeans endpoint implementation , i think in this case, it will be more easier than this.

Comment: Thanks for input! Looking fwd to your update :) --- not easy to google up the details on this...

Comment: Actually , i have prepared a scenario in my system for this requirement, still searching for classes, libraries etc in oracle doc to achieve this. nice catch btw.

Comment: I did find a hint here: 
http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/How-to-register-multiple-endpoints-on-a-same-address-in-apache-cxf-JAXWS-td5735166.html 
(comment by Daniel Kulp halfway down the page). 
I added the property "allow-multiplex-endpoint" to cxf-servlet.xml, which actually eliminated the url/port-conflict error. 
But behaviour still not correct, only one of the interfaces get exposed.
The additional steps to implement and configure AbstractEndpointSelectionInterceptor, I was not able to figure out from the code-example he links to.