# 2 WSDL's or 2 portTypes which solution is better?

Tags: java, wsdl, jax-ws

I am curious about what Java developers are thinking about having 2 WSDLs.

Recently we were asked to expand an existing web service.
After some research I find out that we can extend the existing web service WSDL with 2 (different/name) portTypes. The advantage is that we do not have to generate java code twice from 2 different WSDLs in the same application and maintaining 2 different WSDLs.

My question is which solution is advantageous 2 WSDL's or 2 PortType in the same (existing) WSDL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can also help someone else.

To begin with, I always prefer to expand an existing wsdl 
with an extra portType. Unless it concerns other kind of information where there is a clear separation like Sales/Shipping.

Because it is common to have a wsdl with one portType, 
I found some examples on the internet with more then two portTypes.
[CXF: Implement multiple ports on same soap:adress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20845604/cxf-implement-multiple-ports-on-same-soapadress)

But this solution was not that simple for me because of JAX-WS.
And I found the solution with 2 portTypes in the WSDL.

As prescribed by JSR-109, the **default** URL pattern is constructed using the **@WebService.serviceName** attribute (2 portTypes also, means 2 same **serviceName** derived urls's)

**Step 1 WSDL:**

[image]

**Step 2 web.xml**

[image]

Platforms like Tomcat this can offer a solution with 2 portTypes

[JAX-WS multiple endpoints in sun-jaxws.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172463/jax-ws-multiple-endpoints-in-sun-jaxws-xml)